# Any way to get 4xx response body w/o try...catch while using await?

Tags: node.js, superagent

```
async function checkToken(token) {
  const result = await superagent
    .post(`${config.serviceUrl}/check_token`)
    .send({token});
  return result.body;
}
```

Default options if this call will return 401 throws an Exception, which is not what i expect. API i call is using HTTP status messages also as body to give information back and i just need the body part.

Response with http status 401 is

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "code": "INVALID_TOKEN",
        "message": "Token is not valid"
    }
}
```

And currently, to get this, I need to wrap all superagent calls with try...catch

```
async function checkToken(token) {
  let result = null;
  try {
    result = await superagent
      .post(`${config.serviceUrl}/check_token`)
      .send({token});
  } catch (e) {
    result = e.response;
  }
  return result.body;
}
```

Any way to have the 1st sample working and returning JSON w/o looking at HTTP status?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Superagent by default treats every 4xx and 5xx response as error. You can however tell it, which responses you consider as error, by using `.ok`.

Sample example from documentation (https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#error-handling),

```
request.get('/404')
 .ok(res => res.status < 500)
 .then(response => {
   // reads 404 page as a successful response
})
```

If the function inside the `.ok`, returns true then it will not be considered as error case.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a catch to the request and then return the error as a success response,

```js
async function checkToken(token) {
  const result = await superagent
    .post(`${config.serviceUrl}/check_token`)
    .send({token}).catch(v=>v);
  return result.body;
}
```

Comment: You should have explained what you are suggesting to do. Not just provide a snippet.